# Data Source for CollectionView inside CollectionViewCell is always nil

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` inside a `UICollectionViewCell`, and a separate `NSObject` that is the `dataSource`. I am able to set the `dataSource` for the external `UICollectionView`, but not the internal one.

Here's the cell containing the internal `UICollectionView`:

```
class FeaturedCell: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    let data = FeaturedData()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        //setUp()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }

    func setUp() {
        collectionView.dataSource = data
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.reloadData()

    }
}

extension FeaturedCell {

    func setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate <D: FeaturedData> (_ dataSourceDelegate: D, forRow row: Int) {

        collectionView.delegate = dataSourceDelegate
        collectionView.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate

        collectionView.reloadData()
        print("Reload Data")

    }

}
```

And the `UIView` containing the external `UICollectionView`:

```
class MainView: UIView, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    let data = MainData()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        setUp()
    }


    func setUp() {
        collectionView.dataSource = data
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = createLayout()
        collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
        collectionView.bounces = false
        collectionView.allowsSelection = true
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("WillDisplay")
        guard let cell: FeaturedCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FeaturedCell", for: indexPath) as? FeaturedCell else {
            fatalError("Unable to dequeue FeaturedCell.")
        }
        cell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(featuredData, forRow: indexPath.item)
    }
}
```

Both of these methods are being called, but the `dataSource` and `delegates` are never being set. I  also followed [this](https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/) tutorial exactly (with a `UITableView`, even) and it still would not set the `dataSource` or `delegate`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help

```
class FeaturedCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }

}

extension FeaturedCell {

    func setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate <T: UICollectionViewDelegate , D: FeaturedData> (delegate: T  dataSource: D, forRow row: Int) {

        collectionView.delegate = delegate
        collectionView.dataSource = dataSource

        collectionView.reloadData()
        print("Reload Data")
    }
}
```

and in the MainView

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("WillDisplay")
    guard let cell: FeaturedCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FeaturedCell", for: indexPath) as? FeaturedCell else {
        fatalError("Unable to dequeue FeaturedCell.")
    }
    cell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(self, featuredData, forRow: indexPath.item)
}
```

And for the tutorial you followed this a [Github link](https://github.com/ashfurrow/Collection-View-in-a-Table-View-Cell) for the tutorial, compare your code with that and see where did you missed out.

Hope this will helps.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. The problem was that this:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("WillDisplay")
    guard let cell: FeaturedCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FeaturedCell", for: indexPath) as? FeaturedCell else {
        fatalError("Unable to dequeue FeaturedCell.")
    }
    cell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(featuredData, forRow: indexPath.item)
}
```

Needed to be changed to this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
print("WillDisplay")
guard let featuredCell = cell as? FeaturedCell else { return }
featuredCell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(featuredData, forRow: indexPath.item)
```

}